# SQL convert all bit types to boolean in loop

Tags: python, mysql

Using MS SQL, for a given table I want to convert all columns of type bit to type boolean in some kind of loop. Can't find how to achieve this in an efficient way for say 1000 columns.

**Background of this question**

For some reason, while using Python in combination with SQLAlchemy,  pandas.to_sql() writes all boolean types to bit types. While I was looking for a fix in my Python script, it's probably to fix this using MS SQL directly.

Python script:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('connectionString')
pandasDF = pandas.read_csv("path/to/somehwere/data.csv", sep = ';')
pandasDF.to_sql("tableName", engine, if_exists = 'append', index = False)
```

Of course, I can work around it in Python, loop through the column names in my Pandas Data frame and run about 1000 queries on the database, calling them from my Python script. But sure there must be a fix in SQL Server too, where others can benefit from too.

Help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: There is no such thing as a boolean datatype in sql server. And why in the world do you have a table with 1,000 bit columns???

Comment: @SeanLange thanks for your comment. First part of your comment: how did I end up with 0's and 1's, rather than TRUE/FALSE in MSSQL. Second part: questionnaires with a lot of randomness in the questions asked, and lot of multiple choice answers can generate easily up to a 1000 columns, all boolean.

Comment: The values being stored in the bit datatype can be 0, 1, NULL. I would argue that if you are storing each questions answer in a column there is something a bit off. How can you handle changes to the questionnaire? And what kind of questionnaire has 1000 questions?

Comment: Thanks, will just continue with 0/1/NULL, didn't know bit and boolean is the same thing! And for the other discussion. Image a matrix of 10x10 possibilities, and you can check/uncheck any of these 100 cells (no max), then it's probably easiest to store them in 100 columns for each respondent. What's your (apparently strong) opinion on that?

Comment: Well bit and boolean are not really the same but the bit datatype does a great job storing boolean data. As for your matrix example 100 is an order of magnitude away from 1,000. I would probably store each row of the matrix in a separate row in the table and then have a response for each possibility. I have built a similar database in the past and it works quite nicely that way. No need to change the database if the questionnaire changes down the road, just has different questions and responses. :)

Comment: That's actually a good one, more flexible. Will remember it when setting up similar stuff, thanks Sean ;)